# Cannot access the variable stored using session in Node Js in different api end point

Tags: node.js, reactjs, session, backend

I have the following login api endpoint

```
app.post('/login', (req, res)=>{

new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

    client.query('select * from login_info where username = $1 and password = $2', [req.body.name, req.body.password],(error, result)=>{

        if(error!=null)
        {
            reject(400);
        }

        if(result.rowCount==1)
        {
            resolve(200);
        }
        else
        {
            reject(400);
        }

    });
}).then((code)=>{
    req.session.username = req.body.name;
    console.log(req.session);
    res.send({status : code});
}).catch((code)=>{
    res.send({status : code})
});
```

});

Now after successfully logging in the username variable is stored in the session object.

But I am not able to get the value of that "username" variable through the another api endpoint.

```
app.post('/logout', (req, res)=>{
console.log(req.session.username + " is trying to logout");
req.session.destroy(()=>{
    console.log("session destroyed");
});
res.send({status : 200});
```

});

Now when I make the request to the "/login" API endpoint then the "username" is stored in the session and after that whenever I make a call to  "/logout" API endpoint then "undefined is trying to logout" is displayed.

I am not able to understand why ????

I am using ReactJs as my frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Here set the secure attribute's value to false in the cookies object.

Why ??

What secure does is that it will only send the cookie over the HTTPS connection. Now if we try to use the HTTP connection then the cookie might not be properly send and so it will cause unexpected results.